# Unable to build face_detector for Electric

Tags: ros-electric, boost, rosmake, face-detection, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to build face_detector from https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/people/trunk/face_detector but it fails with the following error.

```
In file included from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/face_detection.cpp:55:0:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h: In statischer Elementfunktion »static sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >::Ptr sensor_msgs::CvBridge::cvToImgMsg(const IplImage*, std::string)«:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:408:55: Warnung: »static bool sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromIpltoRosImage(const IplImage*, sensor_msgs::Image&, std::string)« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:307) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/face_detection.cpp: In Konstruktor  »people::FaceDetector::FaceDetector(std::string)«:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/face_detection.cpp:151:16: Warnung: »sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/face_detection.cpp:151:16: Warnung: »sensor_msgs::CvBridge::CvBridge()« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:64) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/face_detection.cpp:151:16: Warnung: »actionlib::SimpleActionServer<ActionSpec>::SimpleActionServer(ros::NodeHandle, std::string, actionlib::SimpleActionServer<ActionSpec>::ExecuteCallback) [with ActionSpec = face_detector::FaceDetectorAction_<std::allocator<void> >, std::string = std::basic_string<char>, actionlib::SimpleActionServer<ActionSpec>::ExecuteCallback = boost::function<void(const boost::shared_ptr<const face_detector::FaceDetectorGoal_<std::allocator<void> > >&)>, typename ActionSpec::_action_goal_type::_goal_type = face_detector::FaceDetectorGoal_<std::allocator<void> >]« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/common/actionlib/include/actionlib/server/simple_action_server_imp.h:123) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/face_detector.dir/src/faces.o
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/faces.cpp: In Konstruktor »people::Faces::Faces()«:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/faces.cpp:48:18: Warnung: Übergabe von NULL an Nicht-Zeiger-Argument 1 von »std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = people::Face, _Alloc = std::allocator<people::Face>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = people::Face, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<people::Face>]« [-Wconversion-null]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/faces.cpp: In Elementfunktion »void people::Faces::faceDetectionThread(uint)«:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/faces.cpp:154:52: Warnung: »void image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel(const Point3d&, cv::Point2d&) const« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/image_geometry/include/image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h:86) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/src/faces.cpp:155:52: Warnung: »void image_geometry::PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel(const Point3d&, cv::Point2d&) const« ist veraltet (deklariert bei /opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/image_geometry/include/image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h:86) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Linking CXX executable ../bin/face_detector
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/face_detector.dir/src/face_detection.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'boost::system::system_category()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[3]: *** [../bin/face_detector] Fehler 1
make[3]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/face_detector.dir/all] Fehler 2
make[2]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Fehler 2
make[1]: Verlasse Verzeichnis '/opt/ros/electric/stacks/face_detector/build'
```

My setup is:

```
Ubuntu 11.10 (64bit)
Kernel: 3.0.0-16-generic
GCC: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29522/unable-to-build-face_detector-for-electric/) by [bajo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1949/bajo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2012-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

instead, create ur own package with the source code below
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>
#include 
CvHaarClassifierCascade *cascade;
CvMemStorage            *storage;

int detectFaces( IplImage *img );

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
sensor_msgs::CvBridge bridge;

IplImage *src ;

try
{
src = bridge.imgMsgToCv(msg, "bgr8");
}
catch (sensor_msgs::CvBridgeException& e)
{
ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
}

if(src)
{

```
    CvCapture *capture;
char      *filename = "/home/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( filename, 0, 0, 0 );
storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
//assert( cascade );

cvNamedWindow( "video", 1 );
 src->origin = 0;

    detectFaces( src );

    cvWaitKey(1);
```

}
}
int detectFaces( IplImage* img )
{

```
int i;

CvSeq *faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(img,cascade,storage,1.1,3,0 /*CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNNING*/,
cvSize( 40, 40 ) );

for( i = 0 ; i < ( faces ? faces->total : 0 ) ; i++ ) 
{
    CvRect *r = ( CvRect* )cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
    cvRectangle( img,cvPoint( r->x, r->y ),cvPoint( r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height ),                                                                                   CV_RGB( 255, 0, 0 ), 1, 8, 0 );
}

cvShowImage( "video", img );
    return 1;
```

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "video");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
cvStartWindowThread();
image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);
ros::spin();
}

---

Originally posted by [nandhini](https://answers.ros.org/users/1736/nandhini/) with karma: 46 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0